# Use the acclerometer of a iPhone to scroll a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, scroll, accelerometer

Working on a project for school and I'm trying to use the accelerometer to scroll a webpage.

I want to be able to scroll to the top and the bottom of the page. This by tilting the iPhone.

I'm using Cordova as libirarie to get access to the accelerometer.

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_accelerometer_accelerometer.md.html#accelerometer.watchAcceleration

But I'm Stuck.

I'm getting all the time an uncaught typeError so I'm not getting the values of the accelerometer.

And the other problem is that I have no idea how i can use the values of the accelerometer and use it for scrolling on a webpage.

```
<header class="meta">
        <h1><i class="fa fa-flask"></i> Use a sensor</h1>
    </header>

    <main>
        <div class="container">
            <section data-route="some-section" class="front-panel">

                <article>
                    <header>
                        <h1>Instructions</h1>
                    </header>
                    <div id="accelerometer">Waiting for accelerometer...</div>                      
                </article>
            </section>

            <section data-route="some-other-section" class="back-panel">
                <figure>
                    <img src="media/some-other-picture.jpg" alt="a picture">
                </figure>

                <header>
                    <h1>Some other section</h1>
                </header>

                <article>
                    <header>
                        <h1>
                            Some other article
                        </h1>
                    </header>
                </article>
            </section>
        </div>
    </main>

    <footer class="meta">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#/some-section"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-left"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#/some-other-section"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </footer>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/vendor/routie.min.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/script.js"></script>
```

```
//self-invoking anonymous function
```

(function(){
    'use strict';

```
var scrollTop   = document.body.scrollTop,
    el          = document.body,
    els         = document.querySelectorAll('.meta'),
    position    = el.scrollTop,
    oHeight     = el.offsetHeight,
    wHeight     = window.innerHeight,
    $, $$;

//initialize app with an controller object literal
var app = {
    //init method, Cordova is ready to be used
    init: function() {
        this.router();

        accelerometer.begin();

        document.addEventListener('gesturechange', this, false);
        document.addEventListener('scroll', this, false);            

    },

    router: function() {
        routie({
            '/some-section': function() {
                section.toggle('some-section');
            },
            '/some-other-section': function(route) {
                section.toggle('some-other-section');
            }
        });
    },

    handleEvent: function(e) {
        var scroll = el.scrollTop,
            i = 0, 
            l = els.length;

        if (scroll > position && (scroll + wHeight) < oHeight && position > 0) {
            // scrolling Down
            for (;i < l;i++) {
                els[i].classList.add('shrink');
            };
        } else {
            // scrolling Up
            for (;i < l;i++) {
                els[i].classList.remove('shrink');
            };
        }
        position = scroll;
    },

};

var section = {
    toggle: function(route) {
        var panel   = $('[data-route='+ route +']'),
            front   = /front-panel/.test(panel.className);

        this.fp = $('.front-panel');
        this.bp = $('.back-panel');

        this.bp.addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd',this,false)

        if(!(panel == this.fp)){
            this.fp.classList.add('out');
            this.bp.classList.remove('back-panel');
            this.bp.classList.add('front-panel');
        } else {
            // to do: active navigation
        }
    },

    handleEvent: function() {
        this.fp.classList.remove('out','front-panel');
        this.fp.classList.add('back-panel');
    }
};

// utilities object for common thingies
var utils = {
    init: function() {
        // Shorthand selectors
        $  = this.selectElement, 
        $$ = this.selectElements;
    },
    selectElement: function(el) {
        return document.querySelector(el);
    },
    selectElements: function(el) {
        return document.querySelectorAll(el);
    }
};

var accelerometer = {
    begin: function () {
        //update accleration every 100 of a second
        var options = {
            frequency: 100
        };

        watchID = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(this.success, debug.fail, options);
    },
    // Stop watching the acceleration
    stop: function () {
        if (watchID) {
            navigator.accelerometer.clearWatch(watchID);
            watchID = null;
        }
    },
    // onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current acceleration
    success: function (acceleration) {
        var element = document.getElementById('accelerometer');
        element.innerHTML = 'Acceleration X: ' + acceleration.x + '<br />'+
                            'Acceleration Y: ' + acceleration.y + '<br />'+
                            'Acceleration Z: ' + acceleration.z + '<br />'+
                            'Timestamp: '      + acceleration.timestamp + '<br />';
    }
};

var debug = {
    fail: function () {
        alert('onError!');
    }
};    

utils.init();
app.init();
```

})();

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like someone has implemented my idea. Good. But actually your code looks little complicated to me.
In fact, I implemented this idea on my Blackberry Z3 device. And it works great.
I used BB WebWorks HTML5.
Here is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<!-- Including cordova library -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script> 

<script>

//attaching devieready event to the document
document.addEventListener("deviceready", status, false);

//evaluating function when devide is ready
function status()
{
function accelerometerCallback(data)
{
    //displaying actual accelerometer data
    var dy = data.y;
    document.getElementById("ydata").innerHTML = dy;

    //defining a scrolly variable and assigned the accelerometer data
    var scrolly = dy;


    if(dy < -1) //if the phone is tilted upward than normal, scroll the page all the        way to top with great speed.
    {
        window.scrollBy(0,scrolly*100);
    }


    if(dy > 9) // if the phone is tilted downward (almost vertically), scroll the page all the way down with great speed.
    {
        window.scrollBy(0,scrolly*20);
    }

    //scroll the page with human-readable speed (almost slow)
    window.scrollBy(0,scrolly-5);
}

//attaching accelerometer data event to the document
document.addEventListener("deviceaccelerometer", accelerometerCallback);
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<!-- Displaying the actual accelerometer "y" direction data -->
<h1 id="ydata"></h1>

<!--Add some dummy data to the test how the gravity scrolling works -->
<div style="font-size:36px">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).


Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.


Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).


Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Took me 3 days but I got it working by my self, awesome!!!

```
//self-invoking anonymous function
```

(function(){
    'use strict';

```
var scrollTop   = document.body.scrollTop,
    el          = document.body,
    els         = document.querySelectorAll('.meta'),
    position    = el.scrollTop,
    oHeight     = el.offsetHeight,
    wHeight     = window.innerHeight,
    $, $$;

var watchID = null;

//initialize app with an controller object literal
var app = {
    //initialize method, Cordova is ready to be used
    init: function() {
        this.router();

        document.addEventListener('gesturechange', this, false);
        document.addEventListener('scroll', this, false);
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", accelerometer.ready, false);
    },

    router: function() {
        routie({
            '/some-section': function() {
                section.toggle('some-section');
            },
            '/some-other-section': function(route) {
                section.toggle('some-other-section');
            }
        });
    },

    handleEvent: function(e) {
        var scroll = el.scrollTop,
            i = 0, 
            l = els.length;

        if (scroll > position && (scroll + wHeight) < oHeight && position > 0) {
            // scrolling Down
            for (;i < l;i++) {
                els[i].classList.add('shrink');
            };
        } else {
            // scrolling Up
            for (;i < l;i++) {
                els[i].classList.remove('shrink');
            };
        }
        position = scroll;
    },

};

var section = {
    toggle: function(route) {
        var panel   = $('[data-route='+ route +']'),
            front   = /front-panel/.test(panel.className);

        this.fp = $('.front-panel');
        this.bp = $('.back-panel');

        this.bp.addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd',this,false)

        if(!(panel == this.fp)){
            this.fp.classList.add('out');
            this.bp.classList.remove('back-panel');
            this.bp.classList.add('front-panel');
        } else {
            // to do: active navigation
        }
    },

    handleEvent: function() {
        this.fp.classList.remove('out','front-panel');
        this.fp.classList.add('back-panel');
    }
};

// utilities object for common thingies
var utils = {
    init: function() {
        // Shorthand selectors
        $  = this.selectElement, 
        $$ = this.selectElements;
    },
    selectElement: function(el) {
        return document.querySelector(el);
    },
    selectElements: function(el) {
        return document.querySelectorAll(el);
    }
};

var accelerometer = {
    ready: function() {
        accelerometer.begin();
    },

    begin: function () {

        //update accleration every 100 of a second
        var options = {
            frequency: 100
        };

        watchID = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(this.success, debug.fail, options);
    },        
    // Stop watching the acceleration
    stop: function () {
        if (watchID) {
            navigator.accelerometer.clearWatch(watchID);
            watchID = null;
        }
    },
    // onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current acceleration
    success: function (acceleration) {
        var element = document.getElementById('accelerometer');
        element.innerHTML = 'Acceleration X: ' + acceleration.x + '<br />'+
                            'Acceleration Y: ' + acceleration.y + '<br />'+
                            'Acceleration Z: ' + acceleration.z + '<br />'+
                            'Timestamp: '      + acceleration.timestamp + '<br />';

        //starts scrolling up when the acceleration.y is bigger then 7 and
        //scrolls down when the acceleration.y lower is then 2 AWESOME!!!
       if (acceleration.y > 7.0) {
            window.scrollBy(0, -5);
       } else if (acceleration.y < 2.0) {
            window.scrollBy(0, 5);
       }
    }
};

var debug = {
    fail: function () {
        alert('onError!');
    }
};    

utils.init();
app.init();
```

})();

Answer (score -1):

i have no idea about Accelerometer. but i you want make content scrollable with smooth use isroll plugin and Detects single and multiple finger swipes, pinches and falls back to mouse 'drags' on the desktop.

[iscroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-5)

[TouchSwipe](https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin)

[TouchSwipe demo](http://www.awwwards.com/touchswipe-a-jquery-plugin-for-touch-and-gesture-based-interaction.html)

Comment: Doesn't even begin to approach the OP's question.